# Did Sherlock explain to John why he faked his death?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

Sherlock fakes his death to stop his 3 only friends from being assassinated, but does he explain to John that if he didn't fake his death John would have died?

Comment: I think he did, Sherlock said something to John, that with Moriarty dead, he had to explore Moriarty's criminal network and end all. (This part wasn't shown in the series, its my opinion )So him being dead could help him achieve that

Comment: @Vishwa is this mentioned in the book ? I haven't read them  so don't know. The series showed something in quick flashes but as you said it disn't show Sherlock saying anything to John.

Comment: Yes, it was mentioned in the book. but the scene I describe *did* happen in first episode in season 3. I dun remember exact words, but Sherlock did get the chance to say those even though John had no intention of listening to him

Comment: Yes I remember, Sherlock tried to tell all the things that have happened , but John never gave him the scope to tell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly, **whether Sherlock explained the reason behind him faking his death to John was not shown in the show**. It was left for the audience to make an assumption.

The way John reacted when he met Sherlock for the first time after that fake incident, we can assume that Sherlock didn't get the time to explain the reason.

It can also be assumed that, John *realises* that it was necessary as he knows Sherlock very well and Sherlock won't go to this extent of faking his own death if there was another way out of the situation. 
Remember, his only question upon seeing Sherlock (and the reason behind all his anger) was, why he was not informed that Sherlock was still alive.